# why is the first output line in map reduce null in java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I don't understand why the first output of my map reduce job is 0 and null
The output is : url ; number of visits

and here is the mapper class :

```
public class WordCountMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    public void map(LongWritable cle, Text valeur, Context sortie)
            throws IOException          
    {
        
        String url="";
        int nbVisites=0;
        Pattern httplogPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+) - - \\[(.+)\\] \"([^\\s]+) (/[^\\s]*) HTTP/[^\\s]+\" [^\\s]+ ([0-9]+)");
        String ligne = valeur.toString();

        if (ligne.length()>0) {
            Matcher matcher = httplogPattern.matcher(ligne);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                url = matcher.group(1);
                nbVisites = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5));
            }           
        }
        
        Text urlText = new Text(url);
        IntWritable value = new IntWritable(nbVisites);
        try 
        {           
            sortie.write(urlText, value);   
            System.out.println(urlText + " ; " + value);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and reducer :

```
public class WordCountReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context sortie) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        

        Iterator<IntWritable> it = values.iterator();
        int nb=0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            nb = nb + it.next().get();
        }

        try {
            sortie.write(key,  new IntWritable(nb));
            System.out.println(key.toString() + ";" + nb);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Each line of the input file looks like this :

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
```

and here is the output :

```
    0
04-dynamic-c.rotterdam.luna.net 4
06-dynamic-c.rotterdam.luna.net 1
10.salc.wsu.edu 3
11.ts2.mnet.medstroms.se    1
128.100.183.222 4
128.102.149.149 4
```

As you can see first line is a couple of null values

Thank you

Comment: Does your input file have a header row?

Comment: You should move all your code inside `if (matcher.matches())` check to ensure you only write matched lines. Also, your output shown does not match your reducer

Comment: thank you @OneCricketeer , yes i put the wrong one

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct the code

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok thank you. i sent you a message on facebook (found it on your website). can you check it please

Comment: Please do not use my private social media for help. Your reducer shows `System.out.println(key.toString() + ";" + nb);` and there is no semi colon in the output you have reported. Also, as I said, I think the problem is your mapper if statement needs to wrap everything related to writing the output to the context

Answer (score 0):

You get an **empty** key (not null) because your default mapper Text is an empty string. Then the reducer counts that as `0`...

It works fine if you check that your lines actually match before writing the output

Here's a refactored version of your code

```
public class WebLogDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static final String APP_NAME = WebLogDriver.class.getSimpleName();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int status = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WebLogDriver(), args);
    System.exit(status);
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, APP_NAME);
    job.setJarByClass(WebLogDriver.class);

    // outputs for mapper and reducer
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    // setup mapper
    job.setMapperClass(WebLogDriver.WebLogMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // setup reducer
    job.setReducerClass(WebLogDriver.WebLogReducer.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    final Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  static class WebLogMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    static final Pattern HTTP_LOG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\S+) - - \\[(.+)] \"(\\S+) (/\\S*) HTTP/\\S+\" \\S+ (\\d+)");

    final Text keyOut = new Text();
    final IntWritable valueOut = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = value.toString();
      if (line.isEmpty()) return;
      Matcher matcher = HTTP_LOG_PATTERN.matcher(line);

      if (matcher.matches()) {
        keyOut.set(matcher.group(1));
        try {
          valueOut.set(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5)));

          context.write(keyOut, valueOut);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static class WebLogReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    static final IntWritable valueOut = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int nb = StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), true)
          .mapToInt(IntWritable::get)
          .sum();
      valueOut.set(nb);
      context.write(key, valueOut);
    }
  }
}
```